# Waiting for an asynchronous formula (Excel / Custom Functions)

Tags: excel, vba, asynchronous, excel-formula, blocking

I have a 'custom functions' Excel AddIn that I am referencing in my project. It supports functions that fetch web content asynchronously.

When evaluating a function from a Worksheet Cell, e.g. '=MY_FUNC(...)', the cell value initially transitions to '#BUSY!', followed by the result returned by the underlying promise.

I would like to understand how to go about executing these functions synchronously, rather than asynchronously. I have a VBA Macro which applies the function to a number of cells in my project, however these cells are only evaluated once the Macro has finished. Is there a pattern I can implement to 'listen' or wait for the underlying result to compute?

Custom Function docs for reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-web-reqs

Comment: Which Object are you using to do your web requests? There is likely an option to open the request with asynchronous mode turned off. I have also seen people do a 1 ms wait loop until Request Status says complete or failed. I'm not sure how that interacts with Excel formulas though, the Application doesn't execute code inside formulas with the same rules as a macro or event script.

Comment: The web requests are made through a 3rd party plugin, unfortunately -- written in JS on top of MS's Custom Functions toolkit

Comment: The problem is that Excel only has one execution thread, so your spreadsheet wont do anything until the VBA macro has finished. The way I have seen to workaround this is to  use the `Application.OnTime` method. You specify a function that gets called at some later time, which checks whether all your results are back. If they are the function carries on with the next part of your process, otherwise it just calls Application.OnTime again with the same function, kind of like a GOTO jump.

Comment: You could also try hooking into the `Application.SheetChange` event, with an event handler which will usually do nothing, except if any of the cells you are interested in are changed. I don't know if your custom function will trigger this when it changes a cell's value from #BUSY! to a value. The MS help just says that the event "occurs when cells in any worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link." Might be worth testing.

Comment: If SheetChange doesnt fire, you might be able to hook into Calculate